# Javascript Concat Issue in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a code with too many if conditions. So, I want to convert this code to foreach loop but somehow it's not working.

```
if (str_array[0] === "1" || str_array[1] === "1" || str_array[2] === "1" || str_array[3] === "1" || str_array[4] === "1" || str_array[5] === "1" || str_array[6] === "1" || str_array[7] === "1" || str_array[8] === "1" || str_array[9] === "1" || str_array[10] === "1" || str_array[11] === "1") {
    column_data[0].hidden = false;
}
if (str_array[0] === "2" || str_array[1] === "2" || str_array[2] === "2" || str_array[3] === "2" || str_array[4] === "2" || str_array[5] === "2" || str_array[6] === "2" || str_array[7] === "2" || str_array[8] === "2" || str_array[9] === "2" || str_array[10] === "2" || str_array[11] === "2") {
    column_data[1].hidden = false;
}
```

I have total 12 if statements with or condition.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    console.log('"' + i + '"');
    if (str_array[0] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[1] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[2] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[3] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[4] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[5] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[6] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[7] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[8] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[9] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[10] === '"' + i + '"' || str_array[11] === '"' + i + '"') {
        console.log(i - 1);
        column_data[i - 1].hidden = false;
    }
}
```

Loop is executing properly and I got value. `"1"`,`"2"`,`"3"`,`"4"`,`"5"` etc. in `console.log('"'+i+'"');`.

But somehow it's not working. It's working with static code but when I put it in loop it's not working. Is there any difference in qoutes values which I'm getting in for loop and static.

Comment: So you want to know if any of the array values is equal to 1 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following

```
for(var i=1;i<=12;i++) {

  if(str_array.includes(i.toString())) { // converting number to string
     column_data[i-1].hidden = false;
  }
}
```

For reference, [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Oh great. That's what I need. Thank you for this quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can run another loop based on `str_array` length

```
str_array.some( s => s == i ) //== will work fine for 1 == "1"
```

Finally

```
for(var i=1;i<=12;i++)
{
   var flag = str_array.some( s => s == i ) ;
   if( flag ) 
   {
      column_data[i].hidden = false;
   }
}
```

If you want to set the value of hidden property to true, if all values are not as per index, then directly assign the flag to hidden property

```
for(var i=1;i<=12;i++)
{
    column_data[i].hidden = str_array.some( s => s == i );
}
```

Comment: Sure, glad to help.